# Silly Ruby Currency

Tags: ruby, testing, currency, marathontesting

Im using Jruby (thats ruby anyway, running under jvm :D ) with marathon test (a java swing app) and im having a little trouble handling currency numbers.

I dont use Rails (dont know if i can use rails even with marathon) and  i dont know / didnt found HOW to convert a string to a decimal or a double.

My code with maraton is something like this

```
$saldoDisponivel = get_p("com.company.app.view.layout.objetos.JTextField1", "Text")
```

In other words, saldoDisponivel gets a string (ex: 3.232,20).
I also have another string  valor = "100,00" and when i do

```
$saldoDisponivel = $saldoDisponivel + valor
```

Of course i get 3.232,20100,00 (add 2 strings right..lol)

I though ruby could handle those kind stuff more easly.. in java i would convert those on BigDecimails (using java.math.BigDecimal) but on pure Ruby, dont know how.

Thks in advance.

Comment: Are these global variables?  Why the dollar signs?

Comment: Yes, im using them cz im using it on a Module, and there is more than 1 metod on diferrent .rb that call it.

Also i forgot to mention that my main string is something like 3.222,32 .. so.. i tried both answers and it didnt worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use BigDecimal in ruby as well so that you don't have any floating point errors:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

x = '3232.20'
y = '100.00'

xb = BigDecimal.new x
yb = BigDecimal.new y

r = xb + xy

r.to_s('F')

> r.to_s('F')
 => "3332.2"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. i did  x = x.gsub(".","")
x = x.gsub(",",".") and  y = y.gsub(".","")
y = y.gsub(",",".") to work on the separetors and then used the bigdecimal.. thks

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable to use java BigDecimal, you can use java.math.BigDecimal directly from marathon scripts.

`x = java.math.BigDecimal.new '5.0'

y = java.math.BigDecimal.new '10.0'

puts x.add(y)

=> 15.0`

Comment: it works form float numbers... but it doesnt work with numbers like "3.222,32" .. i know i have to parse to remove the "dot" but i dont know how... i use this on java: DecimalFormat dff = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
   dff.setParseBigDecimal(true);
   BigDecimal valor = null;
   valor = (BigDecimal) dff.parse(Valor);

Comment: What ever you do in java, you can also do in Marathon scripts.

Answer (score -1):

```
$saldoDisponivel=($saldoDisponivel.to_f + valor.to_f).to_s
```

Força nisso...

Comment: This solution introduces floating point errors and by using the last step truncates decimal places: `('1.2'.to_f + '2.1'.to_f).to_i
 => 3`

Comment: The conversion to floating point will still introduce floating point addition errors.  See the BigDecimal documentation for examples.